# Regenerating YouTube embed, using the correct syntax in AMP format

Tags: php, amp-html

My website outputs all youtube embed videos as an amp-iframe in its AMP view.
They are playing just fine, however, I get noticed from Google Search Console regarding the proper syntax of them (asking for  one).

Right now, i've gone ahead and added the following code:

```
$ampyoutubevideo = str_replace("https://www.youtube.com/embed/","",$base_content);
$html = preg_replace('/<amp-iframe\s+.*?\s+src=("youtube.com*?").*?<\/amp-iframe>/', '<amp-youtube
    data-videoid=$1
    layout="responsive"
    width="480" height="270"></amp-youtube>', $ampyoutubevideo);

echo $html;
```

which works fine, but my videos are being shown twice since  is being generated but  code exist aswell.
I do suppose that my regex is not correct and I was wondering if you can help me in syntaxing it correctly.

My purpose is to have the  completely replaced with  when embed items exist from youtube.com source only.

Comment: what is in $base_content?

Comment: @BachchaSingh my post's content, straight ouf of a WordPress post.

Comment: AFAIK , youtube embed is use amp-youtube not amp-iframe , https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-youtube/

Comment: A better answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54875596/4518190

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue here, under AMP for WP.
Adding your code, returned content twice, once with amp-youtube markup and one with amp-iframe.

I am adding:

```
$ampyoutubevideo = str_replace("https://www.youtube.com/embed/","",$base_content);
$html = preg_replace('/<amp-iframe\s+.*?\s+src=(".*?").*?<\/amp-iframe>/', '<amp-youtube
    data-videoid=$1
    layout="responsive"
    width="480" height="270"></amp-youtube>', $ampyoutubevideo);

echo $html;
```

and getting:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<amp-youtube data-videoid="zXrdyx43va" layout="responsive" width="480" height="270"></amp-youtube>
</div>
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<amp-iframe class="embed-responsive-item amp-wp-enforced-sizes" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zXrdyx43va" width="300" height="150" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" layout="intrinsic"><div placeholder="" class="amp-wp-iframe-placeholder">
</div>
</amp-iframe>
```

If i dont apply your snippet, I do get this output:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<amp-iframe class="embed-responsive-item amp-wp-enforced-sizes" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zXrdyx43va" width="300" height="150" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" layout="intrinsic"><div placeholder="" class="amp-wp-iframe-placeholder">
</div>
</amp-iframe>
```

Im pretty sure that you need to preg_replace the iframe manually, but im not an expert at regular expressions.

Comment: Found out that this happened due to non-oEmbed use.